# Memoir chapter styles

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, book-design

I'm designing a book collection using the `memoir` class. I want chapter titles to have a page for themselves (before the chapter proper). I'm using the following code for that:

```
\makechapterstyle{renaccs}{%
\chapterstyle{default}
\def\chapterheadstart{\hbox{}\vspace{6\onelineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\scshape\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\vfill\cleartorecto}
}
```

The problem is that most other book divisions (TOCs, LOFs, etc.) also get this formatting---as expected. Is there a way for me to only get this results for chapter titles proper, and not for TOCs, LOFs, etc.? (I mean, I could change the formatting locally and manually at the outset of every chapter, but I will to have a class setting for this.)
Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple example, based on my earlier comment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makechapterstyle{renaccs}{%
\chapterstyle{default}
\def\chapterheadstart{\hbox{}\vspace{6\onelineskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\scshape\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\vfill\cleartorecto}
%\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\vfill\clearpage}% <-- another possibility
}

\begin{document}

% Front matter
\frontmatter
\chapterstyle{plain}

\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1]

% Main matter
\mainmatter
\chapterstyle{renaccs}

\chapter{The First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{The Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

% Back matter
\backmatter
\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\chapter{An Appendix}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Try commenting out the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter` to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks. This actually works. I thought I could manage that only with the (one) chapter style definition.