# How do I set the font of chapters and sections throughout my entire document?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, memoir, font-encodings

I'm using memoir as my documentclass: in particular, the template provided by Jesper Ipsen in [the following question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70824/painless-memoir-class-book-template).

How do I accomplish setting every \chapter and \section to the same font without having to set it manually each time?

Comment: Either you go to the LaTeX Font Catalogue and take your pick or you modify the template to use XeTeX of LuaTeX and load `fontspec` to use system fonts of your choice.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memoir chapter styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53436/memoir-chapter-styles)

Comment: Also related: [Modify default memoir chapter style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97465/modify-default-memoir-chapter-style), [Is there an easy way to change the font and size for Chapter Heading in Memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80558/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-font-and-size-for-chapter-heading-in-memoir), [customizing section formatting using memoir class (color and numbering)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56004), [Font problems in memoir chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121744) …